# Service on AWS to move data from one service to another

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, scalability

I want to build a service running on AWS that would fetch metrics from another service A, also running on AWS, do some processing, and then post it to a different service B for computing overall resource usage running on a different public cloud. The APIs for the existing services A and B are already defined, and are beyond my control.

My principal concern is that the volume of data I will fetch and post may be high, and I may have to do some computation on this data before posting the results. If the service is to run on a fixed periodic schedule, and I need to make it resilient, how should it be deployed?

1. EC2 VM.
2. Lambda.

Additionally:

1. How do I make the service resilient / highly available?
2. How do I scale it with higher data volumes? One thought is to partition the keyspace of the data based on tenant, etc. and perform the computation in concurrent compute instances that are independent, non-overlapping.
3. If I store the data in transit for intermediate processing, how can I make the data in transit resilient?

These questions are from an AWS infrastructure perspective because I have very little prior knowledge of AWS.

#### Sample numbers

1. Input data from service A: 10000 records per minute, each record about 1 KiB. So 10 MiB per minute.
2. Processing latency in the service - maximum 0.1 second per record.
3. Data posted to service B: About 2 MiB per minute. The connections are over WAN.

Comment: What are your contraints for the service? Does the architecture needs to be exactly as you describe it or do you have room for additional resources?

Comment: No it's definitely possible to add additional resources.

Comment: My take would be to do a lambda that extracts metrics from service A, sends it to Firehose from there to S3 and a second lambda to upload the metrics. That should account for resilience and availability

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide more information? For example, which services you are going to/from? What is the volume and frequency of data (eg 1KB every 2 seconds or 10GB once per hour)? How complex is your in-between processing (eg takes 2 seconds vs takes 20 minutes)?

Comment: Added some data.